Optional string showing nil
TableViewController:
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var newsItems: [NewsItem] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewsCell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newsItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell", for: indexPath)
        let newsItem = newsItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = newsItem.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formatDate(newsItem.date)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        return cell
    }

    private func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let newsItem = newsItems[indexPath.row]
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: newsItem.title, message: newsItem.content, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

Update to add NewsListViewModel
import Foundation
import Parse

class NewsListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var newsItems: [NewsItem] = []

    func fetchNews() {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "News")
        query.order(byDescending: "updatedAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching news: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let objects = objects {
                let fetchedNews = objects.compactMap { object -> NewsItem? in
                    guard let title = object["title"] as? String,
                          let date = object.updatedAt,
                          let description = object["description"] as? String else {
                        return nil
                    }
                    return NewsItem(id: UUID(), title: title, date: date, content: description)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.newsItems = fetchedNews
                    print("Fetched \(fetchedNews.count) news items")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I really have no clue what's going on here. I get objects from Parse, it shows them in a table view controller, and when I tap a row it opens a sheet. The sheet is supposed to display the content of the news item, which is from the key description. For some reason, it jumps straight to the else statement of the if let.
struct NewsAndAlertsView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = NewsListViewModel()
    
    @State private var selectedNewsItem: NewsItem? = nil
    @State private var isPresentingModal = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.newsItems.isEmpty {
                Text("Loading news...")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                
            } else {
                NewsListView(newsItems: viewModel.newsItems) { newsItem in
                    print("Selected News Item: \(newsItem.title)")
                    self.selectedNewsItem = newsItem
                    self.isPresentingModal = true

                }
            }
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitle("News & Alerts", displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchNews()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingModal) {
            if let newsItem = self.selectedNewsItem {
                VStack {
                    Text(newsItem.title)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()

                    Text(formatDate(newsItem.date))
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding()

                    Text(newsItem.content)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                .onAppear {
                    print("Sheet Title: \(newsItem.title)")
                    print("Sheet Date: \(formatDate(newsItem.date))")
                    print("Sheet Content: \(newsItem.content)")
                }
            } else {
                    Text("No News Item Selected")
                
            }
        }
    }

When I've done debug for self.selectedNewsItem I get this:
Optional(ChurchApp.NewsItem(id: 2ECF3231-2DB9-4F28-8B4C-6DC1305D50B2, title: "Test", date: 2024-08-06 02:07:05 +0000, content: "Just a test"))

Again the issue seems to be related to the  if let newsItem = self.selectedNewsItem { line of code. But as I'm new to Swift, I'm lost.

Can you try .sheet(item:) instead?

@sonle I'm extremely new to swift and swiftui, so I'm not exactly sure on that.

I mean it's not really a solution.
It's redundant, to have 2 properties with the same purpose.

@sonle ? What???

If I take out the if let statement and just set text to self.selectedNewsItem.title, it crashes because that comes back nil, despite console in other places giving me the title

If you use .sheet(item:), you don't need to unwrap the optional item.

viewModel should be @StateObject, not @ObservedObject.  Use @StateObject when the view owns the object and @ObservedObject when the view receives a state object from another view.

Could you share the code of your NewsListView? I'm a bit confused because of the closure you have there. I would pass the States as Binding to this view and update them directly without the closure. Where did you place your debugging so you get that NewsItem?

@Fabio Just updated

@user717452 Thanks for the update, but I meant the NewsListView not the ViewModel. The View where the selection happens :)

@Fabio Finally got around to adding what you asked for. Crazy last week

@user717452 I'm a lot more confused than I was before... Whats the TableView Controller doing there? Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit? Or are you using SwiftUI Inside the TableView Controller? If so, why?

This behavior in SwiftUI might not be ideal (in my opinion), but you can work around it using a different API designed for this purpose.
You can combine your presentation logic with the nil check like this:
...
}
.sheet(item: $selectedNewsItem) { newsItem in  //  At this point, newsItem is guaranteed to be non-nil
    VStack {
        Text(newsItem.title)
        ...

Note that NewsItem must conform to Identifiable for this to work. If it doesn't already conform, you can make it conform like this:
extension NewsItem: Identifiable {
    var id: String { title }  //  Title is just an example; use a unique property as the identifier
}


You can extract the views in the sheet and use a binding variable in that extracted view. Using a binding will update the view when the variable is updated:
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingModal) {
        ExtractedView(selectedNewsItem: selectedNewsItem)
    }

The extracted view code:
struct Extracted

    View: View {
        @Binding var selectedNewsItem: NewsItem?
        var body: some View {
            if let newsItem = self.selectedNewsItem {
                VStack {
                    Text(newsItem.title)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
    
                    Text(formatDate(newsItem.date))
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding()
    
                    Text(newsItem.content)
                        .padding()
    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                .onAppear {
                    print("Sheet Title: \(newsItem.title)")
                    print("Sheet Date: \(formatDate(newsItem.date))")
                    print("Sheet Content: \(newsItem.content)")
                }
            } else {
                Text("No News Item Selected")
            }
        }
    }


@user717452 is this answer resolving your issue ? If so you can accept it ;)
